# 'Can't recognize runtime TestNG version'

Tags: eclipse, testng

Debugging a test in Eclipse, I received  "Can't recognize runtime TestNG version"

I just upgraded testNG thru Eclipse to 6.9.11
also upgraded Java to 1.7.0_51

Now I receive the following error in Eclipse:  Can't recognize runtime TestNG version

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What is the version of TestNG?

Comment: I am getting the same error. Any leads on this?

Comment: @EnotEnotovich - 6.9.11 as mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

- I also changed my dependency version to 6.14.3 like above comment. (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng/6.14.3)for TestNG in pom.xml
- from eclipse Marketplace downloaded TestNG plugin(latest version),and error was resolved.
- Eclipse : Neon version

Answer (score 0):

Raised an [issue](https://github.com/cbeust/testng/issues/1012) on TestNG GitHub, they have reverted back to the previous version 6.9.10 in Eclipse marketplace. It is working now!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse:
In my case I worked with Maven,retreived dependencies of TestNG with version 7.0.0-beta1 in pom.xml and tried to execute my first program with TestNg,got "failed to get TestNg version from class Javaillegalargumentexception".

I changed my dependency version as 6.14.3 for TestNG in pom.xml and from eclipse Marketplace downloaded TestNG plugin(latest version),got output successfully.